# Azure Function with Spring Boot + Spring Cloud Function unable to locate main class

Tags: spring-boot, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, spring-cloud-function

Trying to run [azure-sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-azure) but encountering a "Failed to locate main class" error when a request comes in.

Build project in eclipse with maven. Updated code based on [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/255) (or else you will get a ClassCast Exception).

Running locally or remotely (after deploy) produces same error.

Didn't change POM from the sample except to point to my functionAppName, Region, ResourceGroup to prepare for deploy.

```
Executed 'Functions.uppercase' (Failed, Id=349ca69e-4548-4af2-b6a4-84bf5afbedb5)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.uppercase. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM] Exception: IllegalArgumentException: Failed to locate main class
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM] Stack: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to discover main class. An attempt was made to discover main class as 'MAIN_CLASS' environment variable, system property as well as entry in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (in that order).
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.getStartClass(AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.java:279)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.<init>(AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.java:99)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.AzureSpringBootRequestHandler.<init>(AzureSpringBootRequestHandler.java:44)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at example.FooHandler.<init>(FooHandler.java:33)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutor.lambda$execute$1(JavaMethodExecutor.java:54)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:20)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutor.execute(JavaMethodExecutor.java:54)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:51)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to locate main class
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.getStartClass(AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.java:275)
[4/10/19 9:03:39 PM]    ... 21 more
```

EDIT: It seems the jar in the azure-functions folder is different than the final jar that is created by the Thin spring maven plugin. The MANIFEST files contain different mains. The azure-functions jar just seems to be the result of the maven-jar-plugin, but it still references the @SpringBootApplication class as its main. Shouldn't that still work? What is the point of using the thin wrapper at all in this example?

Answer (score 3):

For now this can be solved by changing the spring-cloud-function-dependencies version to 2.0.1.RELEASE

Also of note, any application.properties should go in the azure-functions folder after build. This can be done several ways.

Comment: Can you also upgrade to 2.1.1? There were some changes related to that